# Invalid Procedure Call on LEFT function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get the first word from `MAH.[Country Short Trade Name]` till space and write it into a new column `PRODUCT_NAME` but when I use the `LEFT` function it gives me error:

```
Invalid Procedure Call.
```

The query works without the `LEFT` function.

Checked but no period is missing in the statement. Any help appreciated!

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAH.[PDS Id] AS MAH_NUMBER, 
       MAH.[COUNTRY] AS COUNTRY, 
       MAH.Strength, SAPSKU.[Product] AS SKU_PRODUCT, 
       SAPSKU.[Reporting Material Name], 
       SAPSKU.[MARKET] AS MARKET, 
       LEFT(MAH.[Country Short Trade Name],
       InStr(MAH.[Country Short Trade Name], " ")-1) AS PRODUCT_NAME
FROM MAH, SAPSKU
WHERE (SAPSKU.[Reporting Material Name] like "*" & MAH.[Strength] & "*" ) 
AND (SAPSKU.[Product ] LIKE "*" & MAH.[Country Short Trade Name] & "*") 
AND (MAH.[COUNTRY] = SAPSKU.[MARKET]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting a blank at the end of the string - if there are no blanks in the string, you'll get an error

```
 LEFT(MAH.[Country Short Trade Name],
       InStr(MAH.[Country Short Trade Name] & " ", " ")-1) AS PRODUCT_NAME
FROM MAH, SAPSKU
```

Comment: @Parfait's should also work if [country short trade name] is null, mine might not.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, some *Country Short Trade Name* do not have spaces, so `Instr()` returns zero and then at -1, `LEFT` cannot run effectively:

Consider wrapping in `IIF()`:

```
IIF(InStr(Nz(MAH.[Country Short Trade Name]), " ") = 0,
    MAH.[Country Short Trade Name],
    LEFT(MAH.[Country Short Trade Name],
         InStr(MAH.[Country Short Trade Name], " ")-1)) AS PRODUCT_NAME
```

Comment: Does LEFT throw error when it encounters special characters like / within the string like A/B? Thanks!

Comment: `LEFT` simply cuts strings from first character to a defined end point. It is not a regex function. Special characters, `*!@#$%^&*(){}<>//`, will not affect it.